# What is correct: "You've got to be kidding me" or "You are too kind"

Tags: speech

There is a question in my test that makes me confused. Here is the dialogue and I need to fill in the blank:

> A: You are a great dancer!
>
> B: _____. I dance terribly.

That is what I remember (not word by word).
I was reluctant between two choices:

> You've got to be kidding me.

and

> You are too kind.

I knew the former can be used so I chose it. However, after thinking thoroughly I thought the correct choice might be the latter so my final decision was to choose the latter. My reasoning: the former (even though is correct) seems rude. The latter seems much nicer.

When I received the test back. The answer is:

> You've got to be kidding me.

In short, I would be grateful if anyone can point out the differences between the two phrases and show some example if possible too. Thank you!

Comment: I'm moved to point out that the shortcoming is in the test.  See the answer below.  You have understood two idiomatic English locutions and realized that they might have different connotations in different situations.  Bravo!

Answer (score 5):

Depends entirely on the context.

Are A&B close friends? Or are they strangers who happen to be making small-talk?

Because if they are close friends, A could have said to B in a jovial way/sarcastic manner and B could have replied with "What? No way! You gotta be kidding me. I dance terribly."

But if this conversation is between 2 people making small talk(strangers who are just getting introduced to each other), then "You are too kind!" sounds appropriate.

A little more context about between whom this conversation takes place will make it easier.

Comment: Very nicely done.

Comment: Very nicely done II